# Grant permissions to empty Postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I created a new Postgres database using PGAdmin 4. I also created a new user that I only want to access that database. How can I grant the permissions so I can create tables, etc with that new user? Can I do this within PGAdmin? When I try to use Grant Wizard it does not work because no tables exist yet.

Comment: try `grant create on database new_database to new_user;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOP USER CREATION IN POSTGRESQL**

1. CREATE ROLE

   => **create role priv1 identified by 'priv1';**
2. ALLOWING CONNECT TO DATABASE

   => **grant connect on database testdb to priv1;**
3. ALLOWING LOGIN to DATABASE

   => **alter role priv1 with login;**
4. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES

   => **grant all on all tables in schema public to priv1;**
5. REVOKE SPECIFIC PRIVILEGES

   => **revoke TRUNCATE ON table_name from priv1 ;**